# Sharing domain model classes (Aggregates) across two microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

Based on my limited knowledge, microservice can be designed at bounded context level or Aggregate level.

If microservices are created at aggregate level, they might need to refer to an aggregate created in other microservices (as they share the same bounded context).

Should we create the same aggregate multiple times in each microservice (if required)? Or there can never be a case, where we need to use one aggregate into other?

Comment: Just curious, when you say design microservices around aggregates, is that something you're inferring from what you know or a recommendation you saw somewhere? That seems like a tiny scale even for a micro service.

Comment: @guilaume31, I am not saying that 'always' design microservices around Aggregates. It is one of the options (apart from subdomain/bounded context).

Comment: I never said you were saying "always" :) [Much of](https://martinfowler.com/microservices/#how) the [advice](http://www.ben-morris.com/how-big-is-a-microservice/) out there seems to point to BC-sized microservices or bigger, not aggregate-sized, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modeling aggregates, the rule is that one aggregate can refer to any other aggregate only by its identity. One aggregate cannot hold object reference to any other aggregate, otherwise consistency boundary is broken.

So if you model your system with regards to DDD rules, your microservices will be clearly isolated and you'll have no issues.

Comment: Thanks Jan! I agree to this. I found that many DDD practitioners propose the same thing.